# Add COD fees in order total magento

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway, magento-1.9.1

I am using `magento v1.9.1.0`. I want to add "cash on delivery" fees in magento's own integrated COD extension. I need to charge `Rs 40` extra from the customer if they select cash on delivery as their payment method.

I have an idea to `setGrandTotal` if the payment method is COD, but I am not sure what to do?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I need to disable COD for some specific products which I have done with the help of other folks but I am unable to add COD fees. So, I have not done anything till now for adding cod fees in payment method. Please guide me

Comment: Note that S.O. is very good at helping you fix code you've written, and not so keen to simply provide you code to do what you want.